# Vertex mesh won't sculpt

Tags: mesh, modifiers, 3d-view, vertices, sculpting

hey all very new to blender(day 3) I am currently making  a donut and I have what looks like 5 vertexes that no matter what I do won't stop looking pixelated when i'm sculpting. how does one fix this?[image]

Comment: Hello, hard to say, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=NLSkv8XY" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/NLSkv8XY/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a flipped face, you can see it if you display the *Face Orientation* option:

[image]

To fix that, select all in *Edit* mode and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>, also you can right click > *Shade Smooth* to have a smooth shading on the whole surface:

[image]

You should also decrease the view *Clipping Start*, it will allow to continue to view your mesh if you zoom on it:

[image]

And maybe correct the topology to have quads rather than tris:

[image]

Comment: Fantastic thank you!